# cant update password in mysql db and how to insert confirm password in register page

Tags: php, mysql

I having 2 problem in my programming. 
1)cant update password in mysql db.

change_password.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();
?>
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">

<html>

<head>
<title>(Type a title for your page here)</title>
</head>

<body>
<?Php


///////Collect the form data /////
if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
$password=$_POST['password'];
$password2=$_POST['password2'];
$old_password=$_POST['old_password'];
/////////////////////////



$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


if($row['password']<>md5($old_password)){
echo"Your old password  is not matching as per our record.<BR>";
echo"no same pass";
}                   


if ( $password <> $password2 ){
$msg=$msg."Both passwords are not matching<BR>";
echo "new pass not same";                   





$password=md5($password); 
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE registered_users SET password=:password where email:email");
$stmt->bindparam(":password",$password);
if($stmt->execute()){
echo "<font face='Verdana' size='2' ><center>Thanks <br> Your password changed successfully. Please keep changing your password for better security</font></center>";
}else{echo "<center>Sorry <br> Failed to change password Contact Site Admin</font></center>";
} // end of if else if updation of password is successful

} // end of if else todo
}
?>

</body>

<form  method="post">
<input type="password" name="old_password" placeholder="old pass" />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="opassword" />
<input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="password2" />
<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" name="btn-signup">Sign Up</button>
</form>

</html>
```

output

```
Your old password is not matching as per our record.
no same pass

old pass <Text fill>

password <Text fill>

password2 <Text fill>
 Sign Up <button>
```

2)how to insert confirm password fill in register page.
user will enter same password again can check it is same
SignUP.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';

$reg_user = new USER();

if($reg_user->is_logged_in()!="")
{
    $reg_user->redirect('index.php');
}


        if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
    $salutation = $_POST['salutation'];
    $fullName = $_POST['fullName'];
    $nric = $_POST['nric'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $dateOfBirth = $_POST['dateOfBirth'];
    $mobileNumber = $_POST['mobileNumber'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $postalCode = $_POST['postalCode'];

    $serialNumber = md5(uniqid(rand()));

    $stmt = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE email=:email_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        $msg = "
              <div class='alert alert-error'>
                <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                    <strong>Sorry !</strong>  email allready exists , Please Try another one
              </div>
              ";
    }
    else
    {

        if($reg_user->register($salutation,$fullName,$nric,$gender,$dateOfBirth,$mobileNumber,$email,$password,$address,$postalCode,$serialNumber))
        {           

            $id = $reg_user->lasdID();      
            $key = base64_encode($id);
            $id = $key;

            $message = "                    
                        Dear $salutation $fullName,
                        <br /><br />
                        Thank You for registering with us!<br/>
                        To complete your registration  please , just click following link<br/>
                        <br /><br />
                        <a href='http://localhost:8080/xampp/bicycleTheft/test5/php/verify.php?id=$id&serialNumber=$serialNumber'>Click HERE to Activate :)</a>
                        <br /><br />
                        Thanks,<br/>
                        <br />        
                        Site Admin";

            $subject = "Confirm Registration";

            $reg_user->send_mail($email,$message,$subject); 
            $msg = "
                    <div class='alert alert-success'>
                        <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                        <strong>Success!</strong>  We've sent an email to $email.
                    Please click on the confirmation link in the email to create your account. 
                    </div>
                    ";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "sorry , query could no execute. Pleae go to nearest NPC to register.";
        }       
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Signup</title>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/NewFile.css" type="text/css">

    </head>

    <body>

    <script src="../js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <?php include 'navBar.php'; ?>


                <?php if(isset($msg)) echo $msg;  ?>
                <div class="padding">
      <form class="form-signin" method="post">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign Up</h2><hr />
        <table>
       <tr>
        <td>Salutation</td>
        <td><select name="salutation">
        <option  value="Dr">Dr</option>
        <option  value="Mr">Mr</option>
        <option  value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
        <option  value="Ms">Ms</option>
        <option  value="Madam">Madam</option>
        </select>
        </td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>Full Name (as in NRIC):</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Full Name" name="fullName" required /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>NRIC:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="S1234567A" name="nric" required /></td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
        <td>Gender:</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>Date Of Birth:</td>
        <td><input type="date" class="input-block-level"  name="dateOfBirth" required /></td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
        <td>Mobile Nume:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="91234567" name="mobileNumber" required /></td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
        <td>Email Address:</td>
        <td><input type="email" class="input-block-level" placeholder="ABC@example.com" name="email" required /></td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="password" name="password" required /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>Address:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="address" name="address" required /></td>
        </tr>      

        <tr>
        <td>Postal Code:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="postalcode" name="postalCode" required /></td>
        </tr>
            </table>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" name="btn-signup">Sign Up</button>


      </form>
 </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

class.user.php

```
<?php

require_once 'dbconfig.php';

class USER
{   

    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function lasdID()
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
        return $stmt;
    }

    public function register($salutation,$fullName,$nric,$gender,$dateOfBirth,$mobileNumber,$email,$password,$address,$postalCode,$serialNumber)
    {
        try
        {                           
            $password = md5($password);
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO registered_users(salutation,fullName,nric,gender,dateOfBirth,mobileNumber,email,password,address,postalCode,serialNumber) 
            VALUES(:salutation,:fullName,:nric,:gender,:dateOfBirth,:mobileNumber,:email,:password,:address,:postalCode,:serialNumber)");

            $stmt->bindparam(":salutation",$salutation);
            $stmt->bindparam(":fullName",$fullName);
            $stmt->bindparam(":nric",$nric);
            $stmt->bindparam(":gender",$gender);
            $stmt->bindparam(":dateOfBirth",$dateOfBirth);
            $stmt->bindparam(":mobileNumber",$mobileNumber);
            $stmt->bindparam(":email",$email);
            $stmt->bindparam(":password",$password);
            $stmt->bindparam(":address",$address);
            $stmt->bindparam(":postalCode",$postalCode);
            $stmt->bindparam(":serialNumber",$serialNumber);
            $stmt->execute();   
            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

public function registerBike($userID,$typeOfBike,$brand,$model,$colour,$remarks,$serialNumber,$final_file,$folder)
    {
        try
        {           


            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO bike_tbl (userID,typeOfBike,brand,model,colour,remarks,serialNumber,file,location) 
            VALUES(:userID,:typeOfBike,:brand,:model,:colour,:remarks,:serialNumber,:file,:location)");
            $stmt->bindparam(":userID",$userID);
            $stmt->bindparam(":typeOfBike",$typeOfBike);
            //$stmt->bindparam(":otherBike",$otherBike);
            $stmt->bindparam(":brand",$brand);
            $stmt->bindparam(":model",$model);
            $stmt->bindparam(":colour",$colour);
            //$stmt->bindparam(":usedBike",$usedBike);
            $stmt->bindparam(":remarks",$remarks);
            $stmt->bindparam(":serialNumber",$serialNumber);
            $stmt->bindparam(":file",$final_file);
            $stmt->bindparam(":location",$folder);


            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }


    public function updateUser($fullName,$mobileNumber,$password,$address,$postalCode,$email)
    {
        try
        {

            $password = md5($password);
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE registered_users SET fullName=:fullName,mobileNumber=:mobileNumber,password=:password,address=:address,postalCode=:postalCode WHERE email=:email");
//          $stmt->execute(array(":email"=>$email));
//          $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $stmt->bindparam(":email",$email);
            $stmt->bindparam(":fullName",$fullName);

            $stmt->bindparam(":mobileNumber",$mobileNumber);

            $stmt->bindparam(":password",$password);
            $stmt->bindparam(":address",$address);
            $stmt->bindparam(":postalCode",$postalCode);



            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

public function login($email,$password)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE email=:email_id");
            $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                if($userRow['userStatus']=="Y")
                {
                    if($userRow['password']==md5($password))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header("Location: index.php?error1");
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    header("Location: index.php?inactive");
                    exit;
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: index.php?error2");
                exit;
            }       
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }


public function chgpass($currentPassword,$newPassword)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE email=:email_id");
            $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                if($userRow['userStatus']=="Y")
                {
                    if($userRow['password']==md5($currentPassword))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
                        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE registered_users SET password=:newPassword WHERE email=:email");
                        $stmt->bindparam(":newPassword",$newPassword);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header("Location: index.php?error1");
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    header("Location: index.php?inactive");
                    exit;
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: index.php?error2");
                exit;
            }       
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }



    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['userSession']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function redirect($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        session_destroy();
        $_SESSION['userSession'] = false;
    }

    function send_mail($email,$message,$subject)
    {                       
        require_once('../mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP(); 
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
        $mail->Port       = 465;             
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
        $mail->Username="ABTMP16@gmail.com";  
        $mail->Password="antibicycletheft16";            
        $mail->SetFrom('ABTMP16@gmail.com','Muahammed Ashik');
        $mail->AddReplyTo("ABTMP16@gmail.com","Reply");
        $mail->Subject    = $subject;
        $mail->MsgHTML($message);
        $mail->Send();
    }   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not binding second parameter `:email`.

**Corrected Answer:**

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE registered_users SET password=:password where email:email");
$stmt->bindparam(":password",$password);
$stmt->bindparam(":email",$email); // This line was missing.
```

Comment: my actual password is 'test'. when I md5 my password i receive 5d14ea490947742c1cb25953b42e4fc5 in my db.  when I want to change password. when i enter 'test' I recieve error msg that password is not same. how to slove it